# Fix the grid color in ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ext js grid to generate grids and customizing cell colors.
Using a search box functionality the grid rows are filtered, but then the customized colors does not show up.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please refer to these example it may help you
 [click to you old post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904432/extjs-change-grid-cell-background-based-on-value/19905470#19905470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells) is very helpful.

You can style a row based on the values of you data object like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { 
    ... 
    viewConfig: { 
        stripeRows: false, 
        getRowClass: function(record) { 
            return record.get('age') < 18 ? 'child-row' : 'adult-row'; 
        } 
    } 
});
```

The child-row & adult-row are CSS classes with a background-color.