# ExtJS Grid Dynamic Columns with Renderer

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a grid (ExtJS 4.2.1) with dynamic columns from server. This is working pretty well.

[image]

This is my code for reconfiguring the grid after I get my JSON fields, columns and store data from server:

```
var me = this,
            grid = me.getVacationView().down('[xtype=vacation.monthgrid]'),
            gridStore = grid.getStore();

        App.util.Ajax.request({
            url: '/api/holiday/GetHolidayData',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response, opts) {
                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (obj.success) {

                    gridStore.model.setFields(obj.data.metaData.fields);
                    grid.reconfigure(gridStore, obj.data.metaData.columns);
                    gridStore.loadRawData(obj.data.storeData, false);
                }
            }
        });
```

In my server, I have for the column property:

```
newColumn.renderer = "myRender";
```

So that value is also in my JSON, but now I dont know where do I have to place "`myRender`" function so when I call:

```
grid.reconfigure(gridStore, obj.data.metaData.columns);
```

My columns get rendered correctly. (I need to fill the background of the cells depending on its value).

Any clue? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String named renderer has to be part of  Ext.util.Format. So you need:

```js
Ext.define('App.util.Format', {
    override : 'Ext.util.Format',
    myRender : function() {}
});
```

If you can't override util.Format, as an alternative could be eval on "renderer" column before reconfigure.

How to write renderer to change cell value, is explained here: [extjs change grid cell background based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904432/extjs-change-grid-cell-background-based-on-value)

Comment: Amazing, just amazing!! thanks a lot :). Is it possible to disable a cell inside this renderer function? Thanks

Comment: I think best way is just render it empty (return  '' in renderer) :P

Comment: Perfect...My App is MVC, where is the right place to put the Ext.define('App.util.Format')? Appreciate it (sorry but im new with Extjs)

Comment: Your_App_ClassPath/util/Format.js , next add requires: ['App.util.Format'] to your grid or controller

Comment: If your app is not in App namespace, change App to valid or run sencha app refresh

Comment: great!! the first comment applies to me. Appreciate