# Ext.Net 4.0 - GridPanel ProgressBarColumn only for some cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar, ext.net, gridpanel

in Ext.Net 4.0 I need to have a GridPanel like this:

[image]

I would like to have a column that show a progress bar only for some cells.

Actually I have this situation:

[image]

Is it a possible scenario?
Thanks!

Comment: it's not really a `progress-bar` in the normal usage of the word within dev, but I think you mean some sort of horizontal bar graph - or have a missed something?

Comment: In Ext.Net inside a GridPanel, it is possible to set a column as "ProgressBarColumn" type. I would like to have a column that show progress bar only for some cells and the values for the others cells

Comment: you can render progress-bar conditionally by creating render handler something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904432/extjs-change-grid-cell-background-based-on-value , in worst case you can show/hide two control one a progress bar and the another is label based on your condition. I hope that I gave you something useful.